# Corona warning for admob

Tags: android, lua, admob

WARNING: CoronaProvider.ads.admob is not configured in build.settings
WARNING: The 'ads' provider (admob) is not available on the simulator

I followed this tutorial https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/07/15/tutorial-implementing-admob-v2/ for implementing admob.

This is code on build.settings

```
settings = {
    orientation =
    {
        default = "portrait",
    },

plugins =
    {
       ["plugin.google.play.services"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { iphone=true, android=true }
        },

         ["CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.apple"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { iphone=true }
        },
    },
}
```

Why is that error?

Comment: In the `plugins` table, you're basically storing a table (the one which contains plugins.google.play.services) and then replacing that table with another table (the CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.apple one)

Comment: The first one gets deleted, of course.

Comment: I edited post as my build.settings. I have the same warning.

Comment: Now I really don't know. I tried helping fixing the Lua part, now it's more a Corona/Admob question, which me personally can't answer :^)

Comment: Hello...its just a warning..when I put game on real device..everything is fine. Thanks for help :)